# Qt6.3 QML Calendar Error Composite Singleton Type Calendar is not creatable

Tags: qt, qml

I try to use Calendar like doc.

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Calendar{
        minimumDate: new Date(2017, 0, 1)
        maximumDate: new Date(2018, 0, 1)
    }
}
```

But I got this error: Composite Singleton Type Calendar is not creatable.
Any one knows how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're probably confusing `Calendar` (a widget) from Qt5 with `Calendar` (a namespace) from Qt 6.

In Qt 6 that works a bit different, you have to create this control by yourself, for example:

```js
ColumnLayout {
    DayOfWeekRow {
        locale: grid.locale
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }

    MonthGrid {
        id: grid
        month: Calendar.December // this is how the Calendar can be used
        year: 2022
        locale: Qt.locale("en_US")
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I turn this Calender namespace into a widget, which might be opened by button?

Comment: You cannot, these are completely different things. You have construct a widget, a dialog or whatever by yourself as shown above.

Comment: I tried to do. So my first attempt was to use the `clicked`  signal of the `MonthGrid`. I clicked everywhere on the Grid, with no result. I just put a simple `console.log(date)` into the `onClicked` handle.

Comment: I don't really know what are you talking about. You probably have to post a new question contains [mcve]

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74775517/how-to-create-a-qml-pyside6-calender-widget