# How to create a qml pyside6 calender widget?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

0Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/72465868/10985257 I wanted to create Widget, which allows me to click on a calender `MonthGrid` and read the clicked date, as a bonus the clicked date should be highlighted. My lazy attempt was following:

```
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Window 

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainFrame
    width: 160
    height: 160
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("CAL TEST")

    Rectangle {
        id: test
    }


    ColumnLayout {
        DayOfWeekRow {
            locale: grid.locale
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        MonthGrid {
            id: grid
            month: Calendar.December // this is how the Calendar can be used
            year: 2022
            locale: Qt.locale("de_DE")
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            onClicked: {
                console.log("TEST")
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

So far it seems to work, but I struggle with the date. From the Documentation I've red that the signal `Clicked` has a parameter of the type `date` with the name `date`, but I don't know how to access the parameter.

Maybe my approach is to lazy, and I need a complete different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code snippet, I refactored a `DatePicker` component which is made up of `MonthGrid` and `DayOfWeekRow`. The component reacts to the `MonthGrid.onClicked` event and saves a copy of the date clicked. A custom delegate is provided so that we can highlight the selected date in a reddish-pink border.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#8ac" }
    Frame {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "#ffe"
            border.color: "grey"
            radius: 5
        }
        MyDatePicker {
            id: datePicker
            month: Calendar.December
            year: 2022
            locale: Qt.locale("de_DE")
        }    
    }
    footer: Frame {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "#ffe"
        }
        Text {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: datePicker.selectedDate
        }
    }
}

// MyDatePicker.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ColumnLayout {
    id: datePicker

    property var selectedTime: 0
    property date selectedDate: new Date(selectedTime)
    property alias month: grid.month
    property alias year: grid.year
    property alias locale: grid.locale
    
    DayOfWeekRow {
        locale: grid.locale
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    
    MonthGrid {
        id: grid
        month: Calendar.December
        year: 2022
        locale: Qt.locale("de_DE")
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        
        delegate: Text {
            property MonthGrid control: grid
            property bool isCurrentItem: model.date.getTime() === selectedTime
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            opacity: model.month === control.month ? 1 : 0.5
            text: day
            font: control.font
            Rectangle { 
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: -4
                radius: 4
                visible: isCurrentItem
                color: "#fcc"
                z: -2
            }
        }
        
        onClicked: function (date) {
            selectedTime = date.getTime();
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: what might be the reason for the `ReferenceError: control is not defined` in the datepicker at line 1 and 30?

Comment: As far as I understand, the opacity, which leaded to the `control is not defined` controlled the opacity of each day. Since this is presented in the documentation snippet, I wonder why it creates an error.

Comment: Hi @MaKaNu, I figured it out. `control` is used in their definition of `MonthGrid` so, that the default delegate is from their source code. However, you cannot copy and paste the code since the identifier `control` isn't exposed. To make their example work, I made `control` as an "alias" back to the `MonthGrid` control. I also change the opacity formula because I felt it looks better to show the previous and next month in grey instead of invisible.

Comment: Brilliant, how did you figured it out? My biggest issue so far with qml, that I don't really know how to debug correctly. Is it only possible with QT Studio?

Comment: Thanks, @MaKaNu, I have read some of the Qt source code before, so I am familiar with some of the patterns. Most of the snippets I write first use https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/. Unfortunately, not all QML is supported, but, as far as most QML questions on StackOverflow it is sufficient. It is fast since it compiles and runs the code on every keystroke. Compile errors are shown on the left. Runtime errors are shown in the browser's developer mode.

Answer (score 2):

The [QML signal documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#signal-parameters) states the following:

> Signals might have parameters. To access those, you should assign a
> function to the handler. Both arrow functions and anonymous functions
> work.

So you can either use

```
onClicked: (date) => { ... }
```

or

```
onClicked: function (date) { ... }
```

The [QML Date documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-date.html) is stating the following:

> The QML Date object extends the JS Date object with locale aware
> functions.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id: root
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        DayOfWeekRow {
            locale: grid.locale
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        MonthGrid {
            id: grid
            month: Calendar.December // this is how the Calendar can be used
            year: 2022
            locale: Qt.locale("de_DE")
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            onClicked: function (date) {
                console.log("TEST", date)
                console.log("date", date.getDate())
                console.log("day", date.getDay())
                console.log("month", date.getMonth())
                console.log("year", date.getFullYear())
            }
        }
    }
}
```